# When to use & instead of "and"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions, writing-style, ampersand

Are there rules of usage when using the ampersand "&" instead of "and"?

Are they completely interchangeable?

The ampersand seems more casual, but I'm not sure.

Comment: http://clientsfromhell.net/post/1116394387/please-replace-all-ands-with-ampersands-we-think

I think that this joke is suitable here

Comment: The header of this english stack exchange community uses it, "English Language & Usage", probably as stylish decorative purposes (as for the writing of this comment).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are very, very few acceptable uses of **&** in proper written English. Here are some of them:

**&** is especially common when joining names to indicate a firm or a partnership, for example, a law firm:

> Baker & McKenzie
>   Abercrombie & Fitch
>   Crosby Stills Nash & Young

In abbreviations, when abbreviating "and", **&** is often used:

> AT&T (American Telephone and Telegraph)
>   P&L (profit and loss)
>   R&D (research and development)

One rare usage is on envelopes addressed to a couple:

> Mr. & Mrs. Jackson

**&c.** is a rare and somewhat archaic looking abbreviation for etc.

Other than that it is vanishingly rare to see **&** in formal written English, although of course in informal email, text messages, notes, and handwriting, anything goes.

Comment: You missed one very important usage. In the title 'English language and usage' ;-)

Answer (score 14):

> Are there rules of usage when using the ampersand "&" instead of "and"?

I looked through a couple of reference books and both of them said that the ampersand should only be used in company names.

> Are they completely interchangeable?

Meaning-wise I think they are.

> The ampersand seems more casual, but I'm not sure.

It's an abbreviation so one might use it more in less formal writing.

Comment: Thanks! I found this Interesting discussion as well: http://typophile.com/node/12426

Answer (score 10):

I cannot say this is correct but in use I find it very useful.

I often use "&" when two things are related directly but only in a series.
Example: "Michel has experience in Marketing, Research & Design, and Business Management."

Like I said, this most likely isn't correct but it makes sense, seems useful, and if enough people agree then we can change the rules & regulations.

Comment: Great example of a good place to use it. It could be argued that the department name is in fact "Research & Design" or R&D. It's a proper noun, so the usual rules don't apply anyhow.

Comment: If we do eventually extend the guidance to more informal conditions like "agriculture, hunting & fishing" based on common usage, we might consider the style rule that it should not appear next to other punctuation, like "this, that, & the other" or "this &/or that"  ...none of which is considered appropriate in the present set of rules.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand is used inside brackets when referencing (Smith & Jones, 2008:36). But in a sentence, "and" is used, e.g. "Smith and Jones (2008:36) hold that..."

Also, & is used in the reference list of an academic paper when more than one author is cited. But not in the title, then "and" is used.

Comment: It will depend on the style guide. Which manual is this rule from?