# Where did the “&” character come from, and why is it here?

Tags: differences, conjunctions, ampersand

I’m sorry if this was asked a million times before, but neither Google nor the ELU site has helped me out.

I’m wondering:

- What’s the reason behind introducing this character?
- What’s the difference between it and *and*?

Comment: [This post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/when-to-use-instead-of-and) may be of interest to you.

Comment: I think the "why" point of the question is its redeeming point.  And it seems to be answered pretty well in that link.

Comment: You may also like [this series on the history of the ampersand](http://www.shadycharacters.co.uk/2011/06/the-ampersand-part-1-of-2/) *tips invisible hat to @JSB*

Comment: wow, this is a really nice community, you turned a question that shouldn't be posted into a great discussion!

Answer (score 4):

The character is called the *ampersand*, and [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand) should be able to give you the info you want:

> The ampersand can be traced back to the 1st century A.D. and the Old Roman cursive, in which the letters E and T occasionally were written together to form a ligature (figure 1).
>
> [image]
> [image]

As to what the difference is between "&" and "and", the [accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/when-to-use-instead-of-and/3145#3145) to a post (Courtesy: Kit) asking this question demonstrates this quite succinctly.

Comment: oh great, there's an entire wikipedia article on it and I failed to find it. Thanks a lot, and sorry for asking such a silly question

Comment: @Gabi If it were a silly question, there wouldn't be a whole Wikipedia article on it. It's a good question, but you can't be expected to find the article if you don't know what the symbol is called.

Comment: And, of course, the reason that E and T were written together often enough to become a ligature is that "et" is Latin for "and."

Comment: Legend has it that this is the last remaining trace of Tironian shorthand: Tiro, secretary to Cicero, found various ways to abbreviate commonly used Latin words and phrases (as you'd have to, if you were trying to record Cicero's speeches). *Si non e vero, e ben trovato*.