# When to use "and" as opposed to "&"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use & instead of “and”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/when-to-use-instead-of-and)

Is there a rule as to when to use "and" as opposed to using "&"?

eg. Andy and Steve's duties were to grade, guide & proctor exams, homework & projects

Comment: For most purposes, the "rule" is not to use "&" at all in formal writing where the concept of rules is meaningful. Otherwise, if you're going to use them in a sentence where you also have "and" joining other nouns pairs, use "&" for those pairs that are **most closely associated** for the purposes of your context.

Comment: @Daniel, that's odd, when I entered "and &" as a search query, nothing came up. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, I tried "and" and nothing came up.  9That's not supposed to happen.  I found it by searching for "ampersand".

Comment: @Danielδ, that's because the search is rather dumb and can't make the use-mention distinction. Common words like "and" and "the" are not indexed, even when they're the subject of the discussion.