# Does the Oxford comma apply to ampersands?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, oxford-comma

I came across this text on a shoe description:

> Durable but light, & flexible enough to move with the foot.

I am well aware of the [Oxford Comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/172671/37429), so the text would use *durable but light, and flexible enough...* if it was using *and*. However, does it also apply to the ampersand *&* in the referenced text?

Comment: Arguably, using the ampersand there is poor style (and you want to avoid suggestions of poor style when trying to sell shoes!) So the question hardly arises with this example. In running text, the only situations I can see a valid use of the ampersand are to disambiguate (beef & tomato and cheese) and in names choosing to use it. After a comma, an ampersand looks even more out of place.

Comment: Here's a related question about the use of ampersands, which reinforces what Edwin Ashworth says: using an ampersand in that way isn't normal in formal English https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/when-to-use-instead-of-and

Comment: I think it's a typo myself. I think that the copywriter was trying to say the shoe was durable but also light and flexible and just hit the comma key by accident.

Comment: @BoldBen as in _durable but (light and flexible)_? I don't know if the comma changes the priority of the operators...

Comment: @fedorqui I read "light and flexible enough to move with the foot" as a phrase in total. If that was the intention then a comma or semicolon in front of 'but' might have been appropriate but a comma after 'but' would be an error.